# Getting jQuery autocomplete to run on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to get jQuery autocomplete to work, but I can never get the source callback to run.

```
$(function() {
    $('#function_name').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('/autocomplete', {
                search: request
            }, function(data) {
                response(data.comp);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the code I currently have, but the callback for source is never run. What needs to happen to make it run? How can I get it to run every time the text box is updated?

EDIT: I updated jQuery and it now makes the requests correctly. However, now the `$.getJSON` callback is not being called. so it never runs

```
function(data) {
    response(data.comp);
}
```

Any reason why is might be doing this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and seeing if you're getting an error or if your request to the server is failing?

Comment: here is the jquery example http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp . Make sure the returned json ie data.comp is in expected format .

Comment: Nothing shows up in the error console, and the server is never showing a GET request to /autocomplete. I've also tried putting console.log inside the function, but that never gets run either. So for some reason the autocomplete source callback is just never run.

Comment: It should just work. Is your selector correct? Do you have a text input element with the id `function_name`?

Comment: I updated jQuery and it's working a little better. I'll update my OP.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that flask (which I'm running my site off of) doesn't return a response when requested by this ajax, but does if you just visit the page. I don't really know what's going on with that, but I guess the code is correct.